# GTMetrix doesn't get my S3 files' Cache-Control headers

Tags: caching, amazon-s3

i'm working on the following site: www.ekamat.es

When I run the GTMetrix test, it shows an awful result on several things. One of them is the expiration of some of my resources. It shows the following message: (expiration not specified)

Those files are uploaded to Amazon S3, and I've set a Cache-Control near a month (2592000). I can be sure of that, because when I open one of those resources in Chrome and I inspect it with the developer console, it shows the following information:

```
Age:3146
Cache-Control:2592000
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Wed, 04 May 2016 01:46:04 GMT
ETag:"70e17baac2c3e15e2df0064dd2466d4a"
Server:AmazonS3
Via:1.1 7acf1813f9ec06038d676de15fcfc28f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:c4ERes-XPeGiwTOzMEwqyvNZlPtDih-uV77WCI6Jr0OAWnohkHGW6Q==
X-Cache:Hit from cloudfront
```

Also, in my .htaccess, I've this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpeg|jpg|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

So, how would you explain that GTMetrix isn't showing the correct info? are they working with an old version of my site, or it's really a mistake or a misconfiguration by me??

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid:

```
Cache-Control: 2592000
```

...it should be...

```
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
```

...or...

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2

If that `.htaccess` file is on S3, you can delete it.  S3 doesn't process those.  Presumably, though, that's on a different server, in which case you can disregard this paragraph.

After you correct your objects in S3, you need to [invalidate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) `*` (everything) in CloudFront to purge the CloudFront edge caches of the invalid objects.